# Check If Condition in for loop in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to change the `btn.text` when value is 5, but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
fun loopFunction(){
    for (i in 1 until 5 step 2) {

        if (i == 5){
           btn.text = "Timer End" //btn is Button
        }

        println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i want to change btn text when value is 5

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not clear from your question what's your problem. Please edit your post to make it clearer, and not just use comments.

Comment: `i in 1 until 5` means "i in [1, 5), 5 is excluded"

Answer (score 1):

The loop will never reach `5` because [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) excludes the upper value, i.e. it creates an interval that's open on the right, which in this case is `[1,5)`.

If you use [`rangeTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-to.html) (or in its operator form, `..`), you'll get a range that includes the upper value as well:

```
fun loopFunction() {
    for (i in 1..5 step 2) {
        if (i == 5) {
            btn.text = "Timer End" //btn is Button
        }
        println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `1 until 6` if you like it more